# Microphone echos in Skype on Logitech G430 Headset

Tags: skype, microphone, logitech-headset

My Logitech G430 Headset has just randomly started echoing in Skype. I don't have any other voice chat software, so I don't know if it's just Skype.

When I select `Listen to this device` in the Sound window, I don't hear an echo, but when I call the `Echo / Sound Test Service` in Skype, I do hear the echo. Currently it is plugged in via the USB connector that it came with (Microphone + Headphone into a USB), I plugged it in manually and it still didn't fix the echo.

What could cause this?

Comment: It's possible that Skype AND Windows are both set to playback sound from the microphone - having both set up like this would cause some echoing. Try disabling 'listen to this device' in Windows only, and see if this fixes the issue